# Can I hang 100lb boxing bag from wood ceiling beam?

Tags: wood, load-bearing

I'm looking to hang a [100lb combat sports banana heavy bag f](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006K3YL2Y)rom my ceiling as shown in picture below.

[image: basement ceiling - metal Ibeam and wood beams]

Obviously the iron beam is the most stable point, but it's only 7ft high at the low point and the bag itself is 6ft (won't have much room for chain/swinging right?). The beam is also in the middle of the room and blocks a walking path so would prefer to put it on the wood joists beyond the beam if possible.

What would be the best method/bracket/hardware for handing the bag on the wood beams of this ceiling. These basement joists support the 1st floor of my house so would imagine can take a strong load. Can I bracked the bag directly to one beam or do is a cross beam needed? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Secondly, I'd like to hang an aqua bag outside under my deck shown here. Ignore the hook - that's just for plants

[image]

The deck joists actually are doubled up, so is there a bracket that could mount under both of these? Or could we drill right into the beams themselves (probably not great idea right)?

Comment: What are the size of the joists, spacing, and clear span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've hung a few heavy items in cases like this by installing 4"x4" or 6"x6" joist hangers facing each other between two joists and installing the appropriate beam into them. Then drill through the beam, install an eye bolt with washer and nut on the back. Hang the item.

This is similar to what I did but I used a 6x6 and ran my eye bolt all the way through.

[image]

Comment: you mean like this?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hv27hrOz0g

Comment: @AdamHughes  See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks man.  How much weight would you say is safe to run off of your particular setup here?  And does joist hanger take nails or screwes?

Comment: Wow. that I don't know for sure as I didn't test it to failure. I installed two of these and hung a 85 pound swing chair that would hold 3 people and had a 550 pound limit.   I used screws and a double nuts for locking.

Comment: how much weight? well it's basically as strong as the floor above.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to be **sure** you are not impacting the existing support in both cases you illustrate would be to run a new "joist equivalent" between the joists supporting the floor or deck that's just for the bag. The beams supporting the joists would be very likely to have plenty of excess capacity in both cases.

Otherwise: You can drill into the beams/joists within reason - just be sure to do so AT or ABOVE the center (in engineer-speak, the neutral axis - where the loading goes from tension (hole very bad) to compression (hole not so bad) - and the loading on the neutral axis itself is technically zero - at least until you put in a bolt and hang 100 lbs off it and then start hitting it adding more dynamic forces.

If you consider how your floor behaves if a 100 lb person dances on the spot of floor above you would have some sense of the probable impact so long as you don't damage the joists excessively when installing the hardware. But if you provide a new joist  (probably 1 size smaller - ie, if 2x10 joists, a 2x8, if 2x8 joists, a 2x6 - this is mostly for ease of installation - also, you could shim it UP after getting it in place for a bit more vertical room) just for the bag to hang from, you're quite certain not to damage the joists supporting the floor...

Comment: Thanks - so I was told that with the rotational forces of bag, the true force can get up to 200-300lbs.  Do you have an example of a joist equivalent?

I've seen putting a dedicated cross beam perpendicular to the ceiling beams as well - is this what you mean by an equivalent?

Or is a joist equivalent like a new beam basically?

Also I don't think I can drill above the center as a heavy bag bracket attaches to the bottom of the beam